# 'List' constructor not available

Tags: flutter, dart

Trying to create a list of 28*28.

```
final resultBytes = List(28 * 28);
```

Why am I getting this error

"The default 'List' constructor isn't available when null safety is enabled."

Comment: see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List-class.html#constructors

Comment: https://dart.dev/null-safety/faq#what-happened-to-the-default-list-constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'List' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use a list literal, [], or the List.filled constructor instead. -> this is before null safety

Now, They have removed it completely, now you can use List.filled
`List.filled(28*28, 0);`

Refer [docs](https://dart.dev/null-safety/faq#what-happened-to-the-default-list-constructor)